# wordpress head individual php meta description

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, head

I've got a wordpress website and tried to insert the following code in my head element to display an individual meta description for a custom post type taxonomy called "all-cars" but in won't work:

```
    <?php if( is_tax('all-cars') ) { ?>
        <meta name="description" content="text text text" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Could somebody give me some advice?

Comment: I solved the problem. 'all-cars' was not the name of the taxonomy.

Comment: Avoid using that way to add meta tags like that on Wordpress. The tag `wp_head()` is there for that exact reason, if you want to add meta tags manually I would suggest to do it through your `functions.php` file in your theme directory. Even better, use a plugin (generally Wordpress SEO does this already and it is a better choice)